# MS Access: Compute min value of field in form's recordset

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a (continuous view) form.  One of the displayed fields is a date (dt_XYZ).  I need to determine the earliest date in the entire recordset.  I could loop through all the rows in the recordsetclone, but is there a faster way?  I tried `DMin(dt_XYZ, Me.RecordsetClone)`,   but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
DMin("dt_XYZ","Table or Query Name")
```

Comment: I realize that, but it would involve re-executing the very query that was run to display the form, which is very complicated and time-consuming.